# error class is overridden by [type="text"] selector

Tags: css

I use custom css for my **text** inputs:

```
input[type="text"]{
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

I want to change background color — and more — if validation fails adding an `error` class with jQuery:

```
.error{
    background-color: #f9abab;
}
```

The problem is `input[type="text"]` selector has precedence and simply the background color keeps unchanged. I can see it in Firebug / Inspect element.

Is adding `!important` to `.error` the only way?

Comment: be a bit more specific with your error class perhaps, input[type="text"].error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No : you can be more specific in your CSS declaration.

Try

```
input[type="text"].error{
   //stuff
}
```

See [this article](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) about CSS precedence for further informations